# Laplace transform with nonzero intial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Here's the problem:

> $y'' -5y' +6y = -7\cos t -8\sin t$ with $y(π/2) = 1$ and $y'(π/2) = 0$

I have found problems like these online, but the right side of the equation usually needed to be balanced, and it fit perfectly with the y-values given.
Thank you.

Comment: You can always change variables to make whatever fixed time become time $0$.

Comment: Define $x(t)=y(t+\pi/2)$.

Comment: @Brian: Why can't you proceed as normal and then use the give ICs to figure out the $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ values you need?